# GStreamer Python dynamic pipeline construction not working

Tags: python, gstreamer

I have a gstreamer pipeline that currently works if I invoke `Gst.parse_launch`:

```
rtspsrc tcp-timeout=<timeout> location=<location> is-live=true protocols=tcp name=mysrc "
! rtph264depay wait-for-keyframe=true request-keyframe=true "
! mpegtsmux name=mpegtsmux "
! multifilesink name=filesink next-file=max-duration max-file-duration=<duration> aggregate-gops=true post-messages=true location=<out_location>
```

I am trying to convert it to a dynamic pipeline like so:

```py
def build_pipeline(self) -> str:
    video_pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("video_pipeline")
    all_data["video_pipeline"] = video_pipeline
    rtsp_source = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtspsrc', 'mysrc')
    rtsp_source.set_property(...
    ...
    all_data["mysrc"] = rtsp_source

    rtph264_depay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtph264depay', 'rtp_depay')
    rtph264_depay.set_property(....
    ...
    all_data["rtp_depay"] = rtph264_depay
    
    mpeg_ts_mux = Gst.ElementFactory.make('mpegtsmux', 'mpeg_mux')
    all_data[mpeg_mux] = mpeg_ts_mux

    multi_file_sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('multifilesink', 'filesink')
    multi_file_sink.set_property(...
    ...
    all_data["filesink"] = multi_file_sink

    video_pipeline.add(rtsp_source)
    video_pipeline.add(rtph264_depay)
    video_pipeline.add(mpeg_ts_mux)
    video_pipeline.add(multi_file_sink)
    if not rtph264_depay.link(mpeg_ts_mux): 
        print("Failed to link depay to mux")
    else:
        print("Linked depay to mux")
    if not mpeg_ts_mux.link(multi_file_sink): 
        print("Failed to link mux to filesink")
    else:
        print("Linked mux to filesink")
    rtsp_source.connect("pad-added", VideoStreamer._on_pad_added_callback, all_pipeline_data)
    return video_pipeline
```

I define my pad-added callback like so:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def _on_pad_added_callback(rtsp_source: Gst.Element, new_pad: Gst.Pad, *user_data) -> None:
        def _check_if_video_pad(pad: Gst.Pad):
            current_caps = pad.get_current_caps()
            for cap_index in range(current_caps.get_size()):
                current_structure = current_caps.get_structure(cap_index)
                media_type = current_structure.get_string("media")
                if media_type == "video":
                    return True
            return False
     if not new_pad.get_name().startswith("recv_rtp_src"):
          logger.info(f"Ignoring pad with name {new_pad.get_name()}")
          return
     if new_pad.is_linked():
          logger.info(f"Pad with name {new_pad.get_name()} is already linked")
          return
     # Right now I only care about grabbing video, in the future I want to differentiate video and audio pipelines
     if not _check_if_video_pad(new_pad):
          logger.info(f"Ignoring pad with name {new_pad.get_name()} as its not video")
          return
     
     rtp_depay_element: Gst.Element = user_data[0]["rtp_depay"]
     depay_sink_pad: Gst.Pad = rtp_depay_element.get_static_pad("sink")
     pad_link = new_pad.link(depay_sink_pad) # Returns <enum GST_PAD_LINK_OK of type Gst.PadLinkReturn>
```

Outside of this I do:

```py
class VideoStreamer(ABC, threading.Thread):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self._lock: Final = threading.Lock()
        self._loop: GLib.MainLoop | None = None
        ...
    def run(self) -> None:
        pipeline = self.build_pipeline()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.connect("message", self.handle_message)
        with self._lock:
            pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            self._loop = GLib.MainLoop()
            self._loop.run()
        
    def handle_message(self, message: Gst.Message) -> None:
        if message.src.get_name() != "filesink":
             return
        ...
```

The problem is that when I use `parse_launch` my code works fine. Messages from the file sink element make it `handle_message`.
Whether with parse_launch or with dynamic construction, there are 3 state transitions that I can observe with `Gst.debug_bin_to_dot_file` which are:

```
NULL->READY
READY->PAUSED
PAUSED->PLAYING
```

After visualizing the pipelines I notice the following differences:

```
Parse Launch:
GstRTSPSrc(GstRtpBin(GstRtpSession rtpsession0 -> GstRtpStorage rtpstorage0 -> GstRtpSsrcDemux rtpssrcdemux0 -> GstRtpJitterBuffer rtpjitterbuffer1 -> GstRtpPtDemux rtpptdemux1))->recv_rtp_src_0_... -> GstRtpH264Depay rtph264depay0`.

Dynamic Pipeline:

`GstRTSPSrc(GstRtpBin(GstRtpSession rtpsession0 -> GstRtpStorage rtpstorage0 -> GstRtpSsrcDemux rtpssrcdemux0 -> GstRtpJitterBuffer rtpjitterbuffer1 -> GstRtpPtDemux rtpptdemux1)).
```

It seems that the `GstRtpPtDemux` element does not get a `src` pad for output, only a sink in dynamic output.
With the new dynamic construction I handle messages for state changes and I can verify that the pipeline is started state changes from ready to paused to playing, however I never get any messages from the file sink. Am I missing a link or incorrectly linking the pads?

Comment: You may try linking elements with caps filtering. Use `Gst.Element.link_filtered` where filter is a GstCaps that you can create from string with `Gst.caps_from_string` such as 'application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264'... Try your working pipeline from gst-launch-1.0 in verbose mode and look at what gst_parse_launch has found for this pipeline.

Comment: If your source cannot be lauched from gst-launch-1.0, you may alternatively connect the pipeline after creation by `parse_launch` to signal `deep-notify` and provide a callback function such as here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/get-gstreamer-camera-settings-after-initialization/75515/4

Comment: When I take the string pipeline and launch it through `gst-launch-1.0` the pipeline works. I've also enabled `Gst.debug_bin_to_dot_file` and I notice that the final `GstRtpPtDemux` of the `GstRtpBin` of the `GstRTSPSrc` element does not have a src element. Does that need to be created manually as well? I also am not sure how to use `Gst.Element.link_filtered`, is there an example anywhere that I can take a look at?

Comment: You may see: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstelement.html?gi-language=python#gst_element_link_filtered and : https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstcaps.html?gi-language=python#gst_caps_from_string.

Comment: That kinda worked? I modified the `pad-added` callback to be: `        rtp_depay_element: Gst.Element = user_data[0][_RTP_DEPAY]
        filter_cap: Gst.Cap = Gst.caps_from_string("application /x-rtp, media=video")
        if not Gst.Element.link_filtered(rtsp_source, rtp_depay_element, filter_cap):
            print("Link failed")
        else:
            print("Link worked")` which worked correctly and the dot files seem to match with the old. But now there are no messages being processed for videos. Is it a state issue of when I am playing?

Comment: Looks like the final piece I was missing was that I needed to set the post-message field on the multifilesink to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off of @SeB 's suggestion I've modified my `_on_pad_added_callback` function to be:

```py
@staticmethod
def _on_pad_added_callback(rtsp_source: Gst.Element, new_pad: Gst.Pad, *user_data) -> None:
    def _check_if_video_pad(pad: Gst.Pad):
        current_caps = pad.get_current_caps()
        for cap_index in range(current_caps.get_size()):
            current_structure = current_caps.get_structure(cap_index)
            media_type = current_structure.get_string("media")
            if media_type == "video":
                return True
            return False
    
    if not new_pad.get_name().startswith("recv_rtp_src"):
        logger.info(f"Ignoring pad with name {new_pad.get_name()}")
        return
    if new_pad.is_linked():
        logger.info(f"Pad with name {new_pad.get_name()} is already linked")
        return
    # Right now I only care about grabbing video, in the future I want to differentiate video and audio pipelines
    if not _check_if_video_pad(new_pad):
        logger.info(f"Ignoring pad with name {new_pad.get_name()} as its not video")
        return
     
    rtp_depay_element: Gst.Element = user_data[0][_RTP_DEPAY]
    filter_cap: Gst.Cap = Gst.caps_from_string("application/x-rtp, media=video")
    if not Gst.Element.link_filtered(rtsp_source, rtp_depay_element, filter_cap):
        print("Link failed")
    else:
        print("Link worked")
    return
```

Finally I needed to set `multi_file_sink.set_property("post-messages", "true")` as that was also missing from my original pipeline declaration.